# How to convolve images using scipy

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy, convolution

What is the difference between `scipy.signal.convolve` and `scipy.ndimage.convolve`? Difference: `signal` vs `ndimage`

I made an experiment convolving **one** image with **one** filter but with two different functions. It resulted in two totally different images. How could that happen?

That's my filter:

```
B = np.full((3,3), -1)
B[1][1] = 8
```

That's my results:
[image]
[image]

One more thing: why does `scipy.ndimage.convolve` work much faster than `scipy.signal.convolve`?
[image]

Another question: in what way is `scipy.signal.convolve` different from `scipy.signal.convolve2d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference appears to come from how the output's dtype is determined from the arguments.

From the code you posted I suspect your image is of dtype `uint8` while the kernel is `int`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal, ndimage
from scipy.misc import face

bw = face()[..., 0]
filter = np.full((3, 3), -1)
filter[1, 1] = 8

bw.dtype
# dtype('uint8')
filter.dtype
# dtype('int64')
```

In this situation the output dtypes are:

```
sig = signal.convolve(bw, filter, 'same')
ndi = ndimage.convolve(bw, filter)
sig.dtype
# dtype('int64')
ndi.dtype
# dtype('uint8')
```

Apart from that and different boundary conditions the results are actually the same:

```
np.all(sig.astype(np.uint8)[1:-1,1:-1] == ndi[1:-1,1:-1])
# True
```

The rendered images look vastly different presumably because of overflow in `uint8` arithmetic.